# Orbitals and electron jumping

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, atomic-physics, orbitals

Bohr model (tries to) explain how electron goes to higher state(orbit) from lower state(orbit) on photon absorption.But in quantum mechanics, we have orbitals which can at most accommodate 2electrons.

Let's consider an electron that has absorbed a photon sufficient to make it jump from Orbital 1 to Orbital 2.If the Orbital 2 is already filled with 2 electrons where will the excited electron go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the excited electrons can't be stimulated, then the photon simply won't interact with the lower-level electron as the electron's transition is forbidden.

Comment: But how will the lower level electron know ,that the upper level is filled?

Comment: I get it's unintuitive, but I'm not sure you can go any deeper than simply saying that electrons can't share the same state and if you try to force them to be the same state it just won't happen.